# Is 'Boost' a feature or a virus?

Tags: applications, malware, notification-bar

The app 'File Manager' now has a new look, a look that has more of a virus feel and less of an 'Android' feel. Force-stopping file manager gets rid of the addition to the notification bar thingy and removes the app icon from the top of my screen.

Sorry if I sound like I don't know anything about Android, that's because it's true.

[image: notification_bar]

[image: app_open]

Comment: Looks like "turbo booster" icon, some apps like "clean master" , or speed boosters add this kind of "feature" to your notifications bar, check if you have any of those, "clean all, speed all" kind of apps, even some apps to root the phone have this kind of thing (like kingo root), you can disable it in that app settings or uninstall the ofending app

Comment: I do not have any of these apps installed, the bar and icon go away when I force stop File Manager so I think it has something to do with that

Comment: you mentiones you have an app called "boost", if you didnt update the phone recently, and you didnt specifically install it, then it is malware, a wrong tap on a browser popup can install some nasty stuff, some even manage to root the phone and install themselves as system apps, making them hard to remove, what make and model is yor phone?, I have fixed some phones with "unremovable"malware by flashing the original ROM , making them behave just like "out of the box", is it this app? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=file.manager.classification.dir.tree.structure.ftp&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If it came preinstalled it is not a "virus" I wouldn't trust any boost apps on play store but usually these apps kill background processes to free up RAM and CPU resources. Actual results may vary but if it is an default/bloat app it is not inherently harmful. To check if it is a phone app, check its info in the App Manager.

Comment: I do not have any of these apps installed, the bar and icon go away when I force stop File Manager so I think it has something to do with that

Comment: If the File Manager is something the phone came with, Boost must be a feature of it and poses no harm to your privacy and security. It may even be useful as a one click method to close background apps if the phone appears to be performing sluggishly.

Comment: File Manager use to not have this 'feature' and there is now an app called 'boost' with the same symbol as the one in file manager as its app icon that I can't delete. In addition I haven't seen anyone else with this 'feature' even though I have looked through the web for a while.

Comment: Have you recently had an update? Maybe it's a new feature introduced in an update. If it is an app that you cannot delete, it is a system app that has been put into your phone by the manufacturer. If you have a rooted phone, you could use apps like Titanium Backup to delete Boost app. However you should be careful to delete only the Boost app and not a critical system app.